# Bringing columns closer together?

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I have a nav, I need to bring the items closer together though. What's the best way to achieve this in foundation?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/avgydnhb/)

```
<div class="row small-collapse text-center">
<div class="small-3 columns yellow">
    Nav 1
</div>
 <div class="small-3 columns tomato">
     Nav 2
</div>
<div class="small-3 columns yellow">
    Nav 3
</div>
 <div class="small-3 columns tomato">
     Nav 4
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you more explain what you want ?

Comment: I want the spacing between each column to be reduced

Comment: but do you still want responsive and full width?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is make a custom row class (`$row-width: rem-calc(1000);` is the default). The row is governing the width of the nav (columns are contained to the width of the row and will fill available space) and thus the total padding of elements. Example Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kjtybe9s/.

Example SCSS in the [Foundation 5 Docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html):

```
.custom-row-class {
  @include grid-row();
  .custom-column-class {
    @include grid-column(12);
  }
}
```

On a side note, outside of collapse part, to change the width between columns, you can adjust the SASS (in `_global.scss`). The default is here:

`$column-gutter: rem-calc(30) !default;`